# Sporadic Crash Resetting Persistent Stores Between Unit Test Cases (RestKit)

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, crash, restkit

I apologize in advance that this probably won't end up contributing much to the general knowledge base here, but I'm looking for help diagnosing what's likely a configuration oversight that's causing my unit tests to crash sporadically.

I'm set up using RestKit with an in-memory object store while unit testing, so that after each test case, I can reset my persistent stores and each test can run with a fresh database. Much of the time my test suite runs without issue, but often enough to be a deal-breaker, there's a crash from what [I think] appears to be over-releasing a managed object context. All relevant code and crash data below:

**Unit Test Base Class Setup**

```
@implementation MyTestCase

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [[MyObjectManager sharedManager] start];
    });
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    [super tearDown];

    [[MyObjectManager sharedManager] reset];
}
```

**Relevant MyObjectManager Setup**

```
@interface MyObjectManager : RKObjectManager

- (void)start
{
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    self.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:kRDPersistentStore];

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{
                                      @"synchronous" : @"FULL",
                                      @"fullfsync" : @(1)
                                      },
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                              };

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self persistentStoreAtPath:storeURL options:options error:error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error adding store %@: %@, %@", storeURL, error, [error userInfo]);
        // Additional handling
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSPersistentStore *)persistentStoreAtPath:(NSURL *)storeURL options:(NSDictionary *)options error:(NSError *)error
{
    // (NSSQLiteStoreType and storeUrl are used if we're not unit testing)
    return [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType
                                                     configuration:nil
                                                               URL:nil
                                                           options:options
                                                             error:&error];
}
```

**MyObjectManager::reset Implementation**

```
- (void)reset
{
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] resetPersistentStores:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error! : %@", error);
    }

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

**Typical Crash Report**

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 463.9.41, iPhone OS 7.1 (iPhone Retina (4-inch)/11D167)
```

Main thread is spinning the run loop, waiting on an asynchronous test case:
(Not always the case but a majority of our tests employ this method)

```
Thread : com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x047f6f92 semaphore_signal_trap + 10
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x0447f41f _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 54
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x044904d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x0447e726 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
4  CoreFoundation                 0x040fb43e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
5  CoreFoundation                 0x0403c5cb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
6  CoreFoundation                 0x0403b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
7  CoreFoundation                 0x0403b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
8  Foundation                     0x03a71e35 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 284
9  Foundation                     0x03a71cd5 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
10 Remind101-Tests                0x0cbb2c02 -[UTTestCase waitForBlockWithTimeout:] + 233
11 Remind101-Tests                0x0cbb2b14 -[UTTestCase waitForBlock] + 49
12 Remind101-Tests                0x0cbba55e -[UTAPITestCase sendRequestExpectingSuccess:] + 142
13 Remind101-Tests                0x0cb92832 -[UTMessageRequestTests testRequestCreatesFileEntities] + 166
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0408a91d __invoking___ + 29
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0408a82a -[NSInvocation invoke] + 362
16 XCTest                         0x20103c6c -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 221
17 XCTest                         0x20103d7b -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 111
18 otest-shim-ios.dylib           0x0098fcc7 XCPerformTestWithSuppressedExpectedAssertionFailures + 172
19 otest-shim-ios.dylib           0x0098fc15 XCTestCase_performTest + 31
20 XCTest                         0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
21 XCTest                         0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
22 XCTest                         0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
23 XCTest                         0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
24 XCTest                         0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
25 XCTest                         0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
26 XCTest                         0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
27 XCTest                         0x201066ba +[XCTestProbe runTests:] + 183
28 Foundation                     0x03a4b5ec __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
29 CoreFoundation                 0x04054ac6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
30 CoreFoundation                 0x040544ad __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
31 CoreFoundation                 0x0403c538 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
32 CoreFoundation                 0x0403b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
33 CoreFoundation                 0x0403b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
34 GraphicsServices               0x057495ee GSEventRunModal + 192
35 GraphicsServices               0x0574942b GSEventRun + 104
36 UIKit                          0x01e7ff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
37 Remind101                      0x0008d184 main (main.m:16)
38 libdyld.dylib                  0x046c5701 start + 1
```

NSManagedObjectContext Queue thread crashes:

```
Thread : Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext Queue
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x03e250be objc_msgSend + 26
1  CoreData                       0x0108ffe3 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform_privateasync + 83
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x044904d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x0447e047 _dispatch_queue_drain + 452
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x0447de42 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x0447ede2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 78
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x0447f127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x047bfdab _pthread_wqthread + 336
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x047c3cce start_wqthread + 30
```

There's small variations in the stack of the crashed thread, but it always includes `developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform_privateasync` in the last couple of frames before a bad `objc_msgSend`.

My initial hypothesis was that something in my codebase was accessing `MyObjectManager.managedObjectContext` from off the main thread, which as I understand would be a bad time. But I put in a condition to log and pause if the accessor was called from a thread that was not the main thread, which was never hit, so there goes my low-hanging fruit on that one.

I also tried putting some logging into the entry and exit points of instances of the asynchronous `NSManagedObjectContext::performBlock` function in the RestKit library to see if a block was running longer than expected, holding onto a reference to the context, and dereferencing it after it had been destroyed. I would have expected a entry log without an exit log if this was the issue, but I didn't see that. I didn't try the same with `performBlockAndWait` because I'm assuming all synchronous operations are complete by the time my test case finished and resets the persistent store.

I'm really at a loss for even how to go about continuing my investigation into this. I realize it's not a ton to go on, but if anyone has ideas or proposals for tracking this down, I'd be happy to provide more information and try literally anything to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what `developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform_privateasync` actually does:

1. Gets a reference to the managed object context from within the queue
2. Creates it's own autorelease pool
3. Executes the block
4. Calls `_processRecentChanges:` on the managed object context to processing any pending user events
5. Drains the autorelease pool
6. Releases the block (the block was copied before it was passed to this method)

If the block was NULL at this point that would be a problem, but you would have different symptoms. The only things here that would use `objc_msgSend` are the autorelease pool and the message to `_processRecentChanges:`.

You can try setting a symbolic breakpoint on `-[NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:]` and see if that gives you any clues. It's very likely that RestKit is making some invalid assumptions about the lifetime of a managed object context and it's getting over released in your case. If that is true, it's also likely that the opposite error is being made elsewhere - that contexts are being overretained. The two problems more often than not go hand in hand. Your question doesn't include the reported reason for the crash (exception, EXC_BAD_ACCESS, etc.), so it's difficult to be definitive.

`_processRecentChanges:` gets called a lot, so it may still take some time to track this down. The issue would be easier to troubleshoot with the newer developer tools - you should be able to see what submitted the crashing block and from what queue, and you should be able to use Instruments with your test case. It's likely that if you can reproduce this with the newer tools that you will make progress troubleshooting it much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the information, very helpful. I added the crash header to the question (EXC_CRASH), and I'll start investigating the `-[NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:]` usage.